# How to parse this sentence : 夢中で語り合う

Tags: grammar

I tried to parse the sentence 夢中で語り合う as
夢中(noun)で(particle)語り(?)合う(verb)

What is the part of speech of 语り ?

I've tried parse it by [https://jisho.org/search/夢中で語り合う](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A4%A2%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%A7%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%8A%E5%90%88%E3%81%86) but failed.

The context of the sentence is the song キボウノカケラ

> 夕焼けに照らされて

> ** 夢中で語り合う **

> 目指してるあの場所は

> もうすぐだと信じて

Comment: Where did you get these lyrics from?

Comment: Looks like hanzi rather than kanji, even though it's clearly Japanese.

Comment: @user3856370  I get the lyrics from https://j-lyric.net/artist/a055a4e/l044087.html

Comment: hi, @Leebo , I've updated it to kanji from hanzi

Comment: what do you mean by POS?

Comment: it means part of speech. @A.Ellett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first thing I want to point out is that using the Chinese modified characters (hanzi: 语) for written Japanese (Kanji: 語) can be jarring for the reader on occasion.

Before I just give you the parsing, I want to teach a *very* important concept.  That is that some Japanese verbs can be combined to form a [compound verb](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-compound-verbs/).  What you are looking at above is exactly that case.  There are two major identifiers that gave it away.

Identifier #1: Base-II conjugation proceeding the second verb.  Others will call this ます form of the verb.  Let's use 飲｛の｝む as an example.  Putting it in Base-II conjugation, 飲む turns into 飲み.  Then, if we attach 込｛こ｝む (definition [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80))to 飲み, you get the compound verb 飲み込む, which means 'to gulp down,' as well as a few other [figurative meanings](https://jisho.org/search/nomikomu).

Identifier #2: This is not a hard rule, but when you see a Base-II conjugated verb followed by 合う, you can be reasonably confident that you are working with a compound verb.  It appears all over the Japanese language.  It basically means 'verbing together' or sometimes 'come together verbing,' depending on the surrounding context.

With all that said, the phrase you are looking for is [語り合う](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%8A%E5%90%88%E3%81%86), which means 'to talk together.'